# How to define all application colors in one place (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I usually add category to `UIColor` to define all colors for my application. But the colors are not accessible from `xib` file. I can create custom pallete color in interface builder (http://natashatherobot.com/xcode-color-palette/) to use colors in `xib` file but it makes duplication of color definitions. I want to have all color definitions in once place. How to do that?

Comment: It may be time to give up Interface Builder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438804/iphone-app-best-practice-is-using-the-ib-a-better-way-to-design-your-app-or-w/3439305#3439305